# How to install Fabric.IO for a iOS iPhone app built using ionic?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, twitter-fabric

Recently, I have managed to try out `Fabric.IO` with a iOS iPhone app project built using native iOS framework in Swift.

That worked successfully.

I then attempted to try out Fabric.IO for another iOS app built using ionic.

**What I tried**

1. I created a new xcodeworkspace.
2. I ran `ionic build ios` which generated a brand new xcodeproj file.
3. I installed Fabric [image]
4. I then added the Run Script Build Phase
5. I installed Crashlytics and then added the lines of code under AppDelegate.m
6. Then I incurred nearly 20 errors after that. [image]

**My questions**

1. is it possible to use Fabric.IO for an iOS iPhone app built using ionic?
2. if possible, how do I get past the 20 over errors I have incurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are C++ library symbols; you need to link against the following libraries and frameworks:

- `libc++`
- `libz`
- `SystemConfiguration.framework`
- `Security.framework`

Which can be added via *Link with Libraries and Frameworks*.

Comment: Hi it works. May I ask how you figured that out? I want to learn how you can "tell" what was missing

Comment: I recognised the symbols, but actually there is an exact google hit for "__cxxabv1 crashlytics", so I would recommend searching before posting.